# Struggling to see the error of my ways (mysql function)

Tags: sql, mysql, db2, stored-functions

(see my answer below for solution - thanks for the feedback)

It's probably something really obvious but I can't see what's wrong with my sql:

```
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION start_of_minute(
->     curdate DATE)
->   RETURNS DATE
->   DETERMINISTIC
->   SQL SECURITY INVOKER
->   BEGIN
->     DECLARE sofm DATE;
->     SET sofm = SUBDATE (
->         curdate,
->         INTERVAL SECOND(curdate) SECOND
->       );
->   RETURN sofm;
->   END //
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ');
RETURN sofm;
END' at line 11
```

All the more frustrating as the following works:

```
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION start_of_week(
->     curdate DATE,
-> first_day_of_week INTEGER)
->    RETURNS DATE
->    DETERMINISTIC
->    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
->    BEGIN
->       DECLARE sow DATE;
->       SET sow = SUBDATE(
->         curdate,
->         INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(curdate)+(7-first_day_of_week)%7) DAY
->         );
->       RETURN sow;
->    END //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

(NB there may be other ways of truncating the date at various levels - and I'd certainly be interested in hearing about them, I really want to know what's wrong with my syntax - not a different method for calculating the start of a period).

Yes, [second() is a valid function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_second),  and [SECOND is a valid interval](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

TIA

Comment: Did you mean to tag this DB2?

Comment: Yes - mysql is supposed to be syntax compatible with DB2 (albeit that both have some specific functionality not in common). There aren't many people working with procedural mysql yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had already considered that it was getting upset about the types - however replacing all the 'date' types with 'DATETIME' types did not resolve the problem - turns out the problem was a space between 'SUBDATE' and '(' - I never knew MySQL was fussy about such things!

(I'd flag this as an asnwer but SO wants me to wait a couple of days first)

Answer (score 1):

curdate is a reserved word:

```
drop function if exists start_of_minute;

delimiter #

create function start_of_minute
(
p_curdate datetime
)
returns datetime
begin
declare sofm datetime;
  set sofm = subdate(p_curdate, interval second(p_curdate) second);
  return sofm;
end#

delimiter;
select now(), start_of_minute(now());
```

**EDIT**

```
mysql> select curdate();
+------------+
| curdate()  |
+------------+
| 2011-01-17 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE` is reserved keyword, not the curdate?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the function `second()` take in `time` instead of `date`

maybe like this

```
second( cast(curdate as time) )
```

**BUT**

is meaningless due to sub-date for `a given date to seconds`, and return in date format (which still a date)

Answer (score 0):

Should you not use a DATETIME data type rather than DATE?